# SSH ProxyJump but use VRF on jump host in ssh_config

Tags: python, linux, ssh, netmiko, napalm

I'm looking to SSH to a jump box and then initiate an SSH from within a VRF on that box, but use an ssh_config file to do so.

remoteclient => jumphost => device1 within VRF connected to jumphost

Essentially an ssh_config variant of this:

ssh -t jumphost 'sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 ssh user@device1'

On the jump box I can happily ssh within the VRF as so:

```
jumphost ~]$ sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 ssh user@device1
(user@device1) Password:
```

And from a shell I can achieve this remotely using ssh's pseudo-terminal allocation (-t):

```
remoteclient ~]$ ssh -t jumphost 'sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 ssh user@device1'
(user@device1) Password:
```

But for NAPALM (python) to connect to these devices through the jump box, I'll need to convert this to an ssh_config file. Using ProxyJump the connection is never initiated within the VRF on the jump box but with ProxyCommand I can see with netstat (and monitoring connections on device1) that it is, but I never receive the login prompt to pass the password (yes unfortunately it's not yet using keys) and thus I can't connect.

The following ssh_config file allows me to reach the device within the VRF, but regardless of RequestTTY being set to force or -t being adjusted to -tt or -T, I still don't receive a login prompt:

```
Host jumphost
    Hostname x.x.x.x
    User jumpuser
Host * !jumphost
    ProxyCommand ssh -F ~/.ssh/tempssh.config -t jumphost 'sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 ssh ' %h
```

SSH debug just shows either one or two messages (depending on -t, -tt or -T being set) stating the terminal will not be allocated and then the connection is closed:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Connection closed by device1 port 22
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

I have tried using the standard syntax of `ProxyCommand -F ~/.ssh/tempssh.config -W %h:%p jumphost` and then specifying a RemoteCommand under the jumphost's config to initiate the connection in the VRF, but from what I can see RemoteCommand does not run prior to the ssh connection being proxied and therefore I end up with the jumphost attempting to reach device1 outside of the given VRF.

I can't see anything similar for this on NAPALM or Netmiko's GitHub nor can I see anything on stackoverflow or stackexchange etc. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do that with `ssh -q` to suppress the output messages and `nc` to pipe the connection through the VRF.

Update your `ssh_config` file like this:

```
Host jumphost
    Hostname x.x.x.x
    User jumpuser
Host * !jumphost
    ProxyCommand ssh -q -F ~/.ssh/tempssh.config jumphost 'sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 nc %h %p'
```

Comment: Amazing thank you very much, that works! If it's of note, it works with or without the -q suppression of messages switch and will work with -t specified too, it's just using netcat to pipe through the VRF that's done the trick it seems. Only slight delay I had in testing was getting round a systemd cgroup issue (which I've seen elsewhere when running things in a VRF) where nc needs to be run as the local user with the way in which I'm doing this, so sudo ip vrf exec vrf-1 /usr/sbin/runuser jumpuser nc %h %p